# Integral extended to a circumference

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have to calculate the integral of $g'$ extended to the circumference with center at the origin and radius $\pi$, oriented counterclockwise, having

$$ g = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{1/3}} \ \ \ \ , \ \ arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi) $$

I thought I could use the [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), but $Res(g';0) = 0$, and the result to this question should be

$$ \int_{+\gamma} g' = i \frac{\sqrt3}{\pi^{1/3}} $$

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: What is $+\gamma$?

Comment: circumference with center at the origin and radius π, oriented counterclockwise

Comment: Is $g'$ the derivative of $g$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Where g is the function given. Anyway, according to the teacher, the solution should be very quick

Comment: Lol, do excuse me, but my complex analysis is not very good.

Comment: I was thinking about Cauchy's integral formula, but I don't think it works...

Comment: Nope, it's the derivate

Comment: Of course you can use the residue calculation. Apply it to calculate the integral.

Comment: @RafaBudría I get 0 as Residual but the result is not 0 :(

Comment: The function can be analytical or not. If not, the residue can be zero or not. But in any case, the contour integral it's proportional to the residue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got something, but not sure about the correctness of some steps: Let's parametrize $\gamma$ as $z=\pi e^{i\theta}$ with $-\pi\le\theta<\pi$

$$\oint_\gamma g'(z)\mathrm dz=\int_{-\pi}^\pi g'(\pi e^{i\theta})i\pi e^{i\theta}\mathrm d\theta=$$

$$=\left.g\pi e^{i\theta}\right|_{-\pi}^\pi=\left.\frac{\exp({i\pi e^{i\theta}})}{\pi^{1/3}e^{i\theta/3}}\right|_{-\pi}^\pi=$$

$$=\frac{\exp(i\pi e^{i\pi})}{\pi^{1/3}e^{i\pi/3}}-\frac{\exp(i\pi e^{-i\pi})}{\pi^{1/3}e^{-i\pi/3}}=\frac{\exp(-i\pi)e^{-i\pi/3}}{\pi^{1/3}}-\frac{\exp(-i\pi)e^{i\pi/3}}{\pi^{1/3}}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\pi^{1/3}}\left(-e^{-i\pi/3}+e^{i\pi/3}\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\pi^{1/3}}\left(-\cos\left(\frac{-\pi}{3}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{-\pi}{3}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\pi^{1/3}}\left(-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)=$$

$$=\frac{i\sqrt 3}{\pi^{1/3}}$$